# Which version of Windows 7 should I install on my development PC?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, development-environment

I am a .net and java deloper. I have an MSDN subscription with access to all editions of the Windows 7 operating system. I am going with a 64 bit installation. Which edition of Windows 7 should I install on my development PC: Professional, Ultimate, Enterprise, Enterprise N, etc.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Godwin's law prohibits the obligatory xkcd link.

Comment: what's godwin's law? http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/windows_7.png

Comment: ...prohibits it for now.

Comment: nothing is prohibited, just the probability gets higher... it's already reached 1 (it has happened)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to all versions, I see no reason not to install Ultimate.

Answer (score 9):

Put Ultimate on the box and run the others in virtual machines.

Comment: Btw, if you don't want full virtualization, go for http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx

Answer (score 3):

As long as your tools run on the OS it shouldn't matter

(btw: I'm running ultimate and it's working out fine)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Vista, or even XP for developing your .Net Apps 
the reason is your apps have to be backward compatible. 
Remember most users still use XP. 
And you cant sell your app to an XP user even if your app is very clever, because they cant install it. 
And at last .Net is Platform independ , you can use it on which ever windows version you want. (even for Linux)
(excluded windows 3, 98)

Comment: windows 7 ultimate has windows xp mode for testing in xp

Comment: Why not install Win7 Ultimate and run older Windows versions in virtual machines?

Comment: +1 for this, I prefer my development boxes to be rock-stable (I use XPSP3). Test boxes you can run whatever you need.

Comment: @Chris: exactly, that's precisely the point of virtualization. I can develop in the OS of my choice, and test the deployment on any older configuration if I want to.