# Which edition of Windows 7 is most suitable for software developers?

Tags: windows, windows-7, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which version of Windows 7 should I install on my development PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203605/which-version-of-windows-7-should-i-install-on-my-development-pc)

Just wanted get some opinions on which edition is best for developers.

I'll be using Visual Studio 2010, IIS and various non-Microsoft development tools.

Comment: that would be xubuntu :)

Comment: Near duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203605/which-version-of-windows-7-should-i-install-on-my-development-pc

Answer (score 3):

For localization purposes, Ultimate is useful.  As I understand it, you're able to switch OS languages which is great for testing as though you were a user with a different language version of Windows 7.  Changing localization settings in the control panel sometimes isn't enough!

Comment: Yes, it's great that MUI is finally standard now; the old way with the language strings compiled into each executable was ludicrous. It's such a pity MS are limiting this to expensive Ultimate and volume licensing customers.

Answer (score 2):

I am using an OEM copy of Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit - it cost me about $100 online.  I do Silverlight and WCF development in C# with Visual Studio 2008.  You have to install IIS 7 and configure .NET, but I have not run into any issues so far.  If cost is a factor, this might be a good choice.

Comment: Thank you, I was exactly looking for this answer. :)

Comment: Just remember, the OEM copy is cheaper than full version, with the limitation that it is restricted to be used with *one* computer (not sure how they enforce this however).

Answer (score 0):

If connecting to a domain is a requirement then professional is required at a minimum.